# Open Cart Same Product Price in Many Products?

Tags: opencart, product

Hi I have just installed Opencart to test it.
But I see a very irritating thing in it, that many products have the same price displayed, even if they have different price set from the admin panel.
I have also cleared the mozilla and chrome browser cache, and the cache of opencart as well. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be good to know which version you are using, if you're using the demo data, and which products are affected.

One thing is might be is that products have another price set under the "Option", "Discount" or "Special" tabs on the product screen under admin.  These can all override the price under the "Data" tab.